# Change Profile Value of a Dependency In Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables, spring-profiles

I work on a Spring Boot project A, that has project B as a Dependency in pom.xml . Project B is a Spring boot project as well and integrates Spring Cloud.
I have written some tests in project A and I would like to set the property spring.cloud.kubernetes.enabled to "false" of project B, only when I run the tests in project A.
I know that inheriting configuration from a depencency is possible, but is the opposite possible?

So far tried to work with Profiles, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#breaking-changes-in-3-0-x) say you can disable this feature by setting the property

```
spring.main.cloud-platform=NONE
```

You just need to figure out how to set this property when running your tests.

Comment: Added in bootstrap.yaml in test resources, and worked. Thank you Diego!